# Where to find music workshops in Hanoi?

Tags: vietnam, music, hanoi

I am planning to visit a friend in Hanoi, Vietnam.  She's working
and I would like to attend a music workshop during the day, ideally, for a short week.  Where can I find such a workshop?

Answer (score 4):

You should visit http://mmworkshop.vn for more information of music workshop. They organize various music & movement workshops that help people directly involve in creating music and creative body movement. So inspiring!

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE, is this your website ?